# What was the first Hello World Application written in?

Tags: programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does ‘Hello world’ come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602237/where-does-hello-world-come-from)

What was the first Hello World application written in?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602237/where-does-hello-world-come-from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program

> The first known instance of the usage
>   of the words "hello" and "world"
>   together in computer literature
>   occurred earlier, in Kernighan's 1972
>   Tutorial Introduction to the Language
>   B

Answer (score 2):

Let me google that for you.

It was written in [B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program#History).

Answer (score 1):

When I first started programming (20 years ago) my mom told me about her Hello World program she wrote in college.  She used punch cards.

Comment: Wow, somebody up-voted me.  :-)

Comment: It's true that my mom programmed in college with punch cards, would have been 1960-1963, but the "Hello World" part was actually a joke.  B was invented in 1969 so definitely was not in B.  COBOL and Fortran existed at the time, but I don't know if she programmed in those or in straight assembly, as was common with punch cards.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program#History), it was in B.

Comment: Except that according to Wikipedia it was in B.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first Hello World was written in C and published in the book [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#.22Hello.2C_world.22_example).

Comment: Of course! A B implementation came before the C implementation!