# Where does the "Hello World!" example come from?

Tags: fortran, cobol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does ‘Hello world’ come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602237/where-does-hello-world-come-from)

`"Hello world!"` is the most commonly used example I can think of, yet I don't really know where it came from. Was it used by some particular book, or did it just spread among developers? Did people write `"Hello world!"` snippets in COBOL or FORTRAN ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick search on wikipedia gaves :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program#History

> The first known instance of the usage
>   of the words "hello" and "world" 
>   together in computer literature
>   occurred earlier, in Kernighan's 1972 
>   Tutorial Introduction to the Language
>   B