# Why is Hello World used in programming examples?

Tags: language-agnostic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does ‘Hello world’ come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602237/where-does-hello-world-come-from)

Why are most all programming examples written to print the specific phrase `Hello World`? Sometimes you see derivatives like `ohai world` and such, but always branching from Hello World. Does anybody no why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple program like this gives a good example of the syntax of the language, structure of the program, things like that.